# Everything right, still an error. Why?

Tags: pdftex

Everything shows up OK after compiling.
But at the line with `\end{align}` I still get an error:

> Missing $ inserted. \end{align}

Why?

I want to have a larger epsilon. It's tiny now. How ?

`\huge` does not seem to work...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=4.6cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=4.0cm,marginparwidth=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{numprint}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}    
\begin{align}
    \tag{EN 40-3-3 pag.4}
    \epsilon &= \bigg(\frac{\bar{R}}{t}\bigg) \cdot \sqrt{\frac{f_y}{E}}\\
    &= \bigg(\frac{66.00}{3.00}\bigg) \cdot \sqrt{\frac{335.0}{210000}}
    \marginnote{\epsilon = \SI{0.88}{}}\\
    &= \SI{0.88}{}
\end{align} % <--- here!!!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many macros (such as \hbox) will take you out of math mode.  Obvisosuly, \marginnote is one of them.

Comment: I confirm it works with `\marginnote{$ ... $}`. Unrelated: what's the point of writing `\SI{0.88}{}` rather than a plain `0.88` here?

Comment: unrelated to the error but `\bigg(  \bigg)` should be `\biggl(  \biggr)` or you lose the mathopen mathclose spacing

Comment: What's the reason for `numprint`, given that you already load `siunitx`? Also note that `\SI{0.88}{}` should rather be `\num{0.88}`.

Comment: I'm going to object to your title.  When TeX hits an error, it guesses at a possible resolution.  Just because it guesses closely enough to give you output you like doesn't mean that everything is right.

Comment: @Teepeemm: I'm writing a C# program that generates a .tex file. So I'm programming in two very different languages: C# an LaTex. C# just gives me accurate error messages: It says precisely where the point comma or brace is missing. LaTex seems to be more "flexible"  in that respect: the messages seem to be more obscure. As you must have "guessed": I am brand new to LaTex.Still, my output looks very nice in LaTex/PDF

Comment: I think everyone will agree with the statement, "TeX gives terrible error messages."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tha main problem (already pointed out by MadyYuvi) is that the contents of `\marginnote` is always typeset in text mode, so you need to explicitly start math mode inside it.

With some adjustments and with a “larger epsilon”, actually a calligraphic E.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=4.6cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=4.0cm,marginparwidth=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}    

\begin{align*}
  \tag{EN 40-3-3 pag.4}
  \mathcal{E}
  &= \biggl(\frac{\bar{R}}{t}\biggr) \sqrt{\frac{f_y}{E}}\\
  &= \biggl(\frac{\num{66.00}}{\num{3.00}}\biggr) \sqrt{\frac{\num{335.0}}{\num{210000}}}
    \marginnote{$\mathcal{E} = \num{0.88}$}\\
  &= \num{0.88}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

1. Since `mathptmx` uses a different style for calligraphic letters, I defined them to be like with the default Computer Modern.
2. I removed the call for `numprint`, that does much less than `siunitx`.
3. I removed the useless `\cdot` symbols; I'd also remove the big parentheses.
4. All explicit numbers have been set with `\num`.
5. In particular, `\SI{0.88}{}` is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`\marginnote` is not a mathmode tag, you should give `$` inside `\marginnote` if math comes, modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=4.6cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=4.0cm,marginparwidth=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{numprint}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}    
\begin{align}
    \tag{EN 40-3-3 pag.4}
    \epsilon &= \biggl(\frac{\bar{R}}{t}\biggr) \cdot \sqrt{\frac{f_y}{E}}\\
    &= \biggl(\frac{66.00}{3.00}\biggr) \cdot \sqrt{\frac{335.0}{210000}}
    \marginnote{$\epsilon = \SI{0.88}{}$}\\
    &= \SI{0.88}{}
\end{align} % <--- here!!!
\end{document}
```